Mouse pointer invisible when moving to a different screen in VMware guest
I'm using Windows 10 as guest in a Windows 10 host, with multiple monitors (laptop + external screens). The problem is that when using the multiple screen option in VMware the mouse pointer disappears when the pointer is moved to an other screen (and reappears when moved back to the initial screen).
The pointer will appear on the other screen if the mouse is clicked, and that click doesn't actually do anything other than make the pointer appear. To select a window, for example, an additional click is required.
I expect the pointer to not disappear, as when working with multiple screens on the host.
VMware Workstation 16 Pro 16.2.5

This is by design. As the mouse is not captured, you don't see it. What exactly is your question?

To be clear: you are saying that you have enabled multiple monitors in the VM, but the guest OS is not showing a cursor on all monitors except for the primary monitor?

Updating VMware (to 17.5.2) resolved this issue.
